# Validating a blank field in Excel using macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a little bit difficulty in validating a blank field.

When I open a file using this code, it opens the file, checks for the application Number in that column (here in my the application numbers are in first column)

What I am trying to do is, if there is no application number present then it should write out the following error "Blank application number found at following Row number"

```
'Global Variables

 Dim rErr As Integer

'
' Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
'

Function LastRowInOneColumn(ColNo As String) As Long

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColNo).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

   LastRowInOneColumn = LastRow

End Function

'
' Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example
'

Function LastColumnInOneRow(RowNo As String)

    Dim LastCol As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    LastColumnInOneRow = LastCol

    'MsgBox LastCol

End Function

'
' To Check Application Number
'

Function Check_AppNo(appNo, pRow, Lrow) As Boolean

    Check_AppNo = True

    Dim MinAppNo, MaxAppNo As Single

    MinAppNo = 0
    MaxAppNo = 9999999999#

    If (appNo < MinAppNo Or appNo > MaxAppNo) Then
        Worksheets("Error_Results").Cells(rErr, 1) = "Application number out of range at Row " & i
        rErr = rErr + 1
        Check_AppNo = False
    End If

    For j = pRow + 1 To Lrow
        If (appNo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1)) Then
            Worksheets("Error_Results").Cells(rErr, 1) = "Duplicate Application numbers at Rows " & pRow & " and " & j
            rErr = rErr + 1
            Check_AppNo = False
        End If
    Next j

End Function

Function OpenFile() As String
  NewFN = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*",         Title:="Please select a file")
  If NewFN = False Then
    ' They pressed Cancel
    OpenFile = ""
    'MsgBox "Stopping because you did not select a file"
    Exit Function
  Else
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=NewFN
    iPos = InStr(1, NewFN, "\") + 1
    ipos1 = 0
    Do
        ipos1 = InStr(iPos, NewFN, "\") + 1
        If (ipos1 <> 1) Then
             iPos = ipos1
        End If
    Loop Until (ipos1 = 1)
    OpenFile = Mid(NewFN, iPos, Len(NewFN) - iPos + 1)
  End If
End Function

Sub AddWorkSheet(fName As String, sName As String)
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Workbooks(fName).Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wSheet = Worksheets(sName)
    If wSheet Is Nothing Then
         Worksheets.Add().Name = sName
    Else
         Worksheets(sName).Clear   
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub validate()

    Dim fName As String
    Dim aName As String
    Dim flag As Variant

    fName = OpenFile()           ' Open the required data file

    If (fName = "") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call AddWorkSheet(fName, "Error_Results")  ' Add Error Worksheet to the data Excel File
    rErr = 1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    LastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A")       ' Get The Last Row in Column

    For pRow = 2 To LastRow

        rerr1 = rErr

        appNo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(pRow, 1)
        flag = Check_AppNo(appNo, pRow, LastRow)

    Next pRow        'Process the next Record in Error_Results WorkSheet

    Workbooks(fName).Close (True) ' Closes an opened workbook on which the validation was done

End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()

    Call validate

End Sub
```

Follow these steps to run the code:

- Step 1: first make a excel file with name say "abc1"
- Step 2: in that file, in column 1, give its heading as "application number"
- Step 3: Now type the application numbers in it(any number you want) and in-between leave one cell blank
- Step 4: Make another excel file say "validator"
- Step 5: in that place a button from the developer tab
- Step 6: in developer tab, click on visual basic
- Step 7: you will see a visual basic editor
- Step 8: on left hand side you will see a project explorer window, in that right click on bold name>select insert>module
- Step 9: then Copy and paste the above mentioned code as it is
- Step 10: Save it and also save the excel file as macro enabled file
- Step 11: Now open the file "validator" and in that click on the button to run the code

you will get the idea what i am trying to say, if you see the code, it's very easy to understand

Hope, anyone can help me on this

Comment: *it should write out the following error "Blank application number found at following Row number"*: In your code, there is no such message. Can you clarify?

Comment: yes you are right there is no such line as you have mentioned, i want to add this feature in the above code, if you could just give me head-start what to do to add the following feature (i.e. if there is a blank field than it should write down the error in a separate excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, I'm not certain if I get it right because it seems simple, but are you looking for something like:

```
Sub Test()

dim lAppNo as long
dim sError as string 
dim lRow as long
dim lLastRow as long
dim bFlag as boolean

For lRow = 2 To lLastRow            

    rerr1 = rErr            

    lappNo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 1).value

    'Or put this in a function if you want to
    if lAppNO = 0 then 
        sError = "Blank application number found at following Row number " & lRow
        Call Write_Error(sError)
    end if

    bFlag = Check_AppNo(lAppNo, lRow, lLastRow)            

Next lRow  
End Sub

Sub Write_Error(sError As String)

Dim sPath               As String
Dim sFile               As String
Dim oBook               As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet              As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oRange              As Excel.Range
Dim iRange_Row          As Integer


sPath = "U:/"
sFile = "Errors.xls"
Set oBook = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)
Set oSheet = oBook.Sheets("Errors")

If oSheet.Range("A1") <> "" Then
    Set oRange = oSheet.UsedRange
    iRange_Row = oRange.Rows.Count + 1
    oSheet.Cells(iRange_Row, 1).Value = Now
    oSheet.Cells(iRange_Row, 2).Value = sError
Else
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = Now
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = sError
End If

oBook.Save
oBook.Close

Set oRange = Nothing
Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

If the cell is blank, the value returned will be zero if AppNo is defined with a numeric datatype.
If AppNo would be declared as a String, it would return an empty string: **""**
I notice that you don't use the Option Explicit, because not all variables were declared.
I advise you to do so, to keep your code more easily maintainable.
Als use some convention when typing variables.

Comment: thank you for the reply and I'll try to follow the coding conventions that you have stated above and I'll get back to you  after trying and implementing it in the code.

Comment: i have tried the ways you told me to do so but i'm still getting an error(i.e. i'm still not able to write down the error in the separate excel file) here is the piece of code that i have wrote down in the below the line of "flag" in the main code

Comment: lAppNo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(pRow, 1).Value
                
                     If (lAppNo = "") Then
                    Worksheets("Error_Results").Cells(rErr, 1) = "Application Number Field blank at row " & pRow
                    rErr = rErr + 1
                End If

Comment: i have declared lAppNo as string but when i run the code it doesn't write down the error in the separate excel file.

Comment: What is the error you get? I'm positive that my code should work. Are you sure that you correctly embedded the condition in the loop?

Comment: when i run the code it runs perfectly, but it doesn't write down the error in a separate excel file and also if you see my code in the question, i have set a range for application number, also what i am trying to do is if there is blank field encountered while running the code then it should write down the error in a separate excel file.

Comment: I've updated my reply with a basic routine that writes errors to a report. Note that it is a very basic example of a routine, you can of course adapt it anyway you need it.

Comment: thank you for the help, the above code helped me a lot and made me realize where i was doing mistake.